# Customize selected Item Surface3d

Tags: qt, qml, customization

how i can change that item when i click on that in surface3d?

**i wanna show a 3dmodel instead of that sphere or ... just wanna customize it**

i searched in google and qt docs and all properties in qml but no solution...

[image: i mean red sphere]

[image: zoomed]

forExample ==> MySurface.qml :

```
Surface3D
{
    id:mySurface
    Surface3DSeries
    {
        id:mySeries
        drawMode: Surface3DSeries.DrawSurface
        ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy
        {
            id:myModel
            itemModel: ListModel{
                ListElement
                {
                    // added some points like :
                    idNumber:"10"
                    cost:"4900"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code, and describe what you have tried.

Comment: i added an example code ... but it didnt need ! just its looks like spam.
because i said i didnt find any solution it's mean no proprety or anyhing found for trying !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I used an Idea for finding third point ...

> Note: added custome item before changing its position.

i used :

```
        selectionMode: AbstractGraph3D.SelectionMultiSeries
        onSelectedElementChanged:
        {
            var xPoint=mySeries.selectedPoint.x;
            var yPoint=mySeries.selectedPoint.y;
            var i;
            if(xPoint!=-1)
            {
                for(i=0;i<myListModel.count;++i)
                {
                    if(myListModel.get(i).idNumber==xPoint
                            &&  myListModel.get(i).cost==yPoint)
                    {
                        myCustom3DItem.position=Qt.vector3d(yPoint,myListModel.get(i).height,xPoint);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for Answer.
we have a problem that is we not talking about a 2d scene and i need to know 3 points when clicking ...
i mean that we need know Qt.Vector3d(...) clicked on Surface3d , and when i know that i can create some CustomeItem [like this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-customitems-example.html)

i created objects in my surface but now i want change that sphere when clicking in 3d and i cant find any property or any function that giving point(Qt.Vector3d) by clicking in surfac3d.

> In addition: we cant use TapHandler or MouseArea in Surface3D ...

Thank you for trying to help .